# ADMIN panel doesn't operate

Tags: php, mysql, forms, admin

This is my admin panel for Add and Delete users from the members table in my database but when I press OK it doesn't operate:

I don't know where the problem is.
I'm not pro in PHP so please provide easy to understand answers.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $user="admin";
    $pass="whatever";
    $host="localhost";
    $db_name="login";

    $con=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $id       = ($_POST['id']);
    $password = md5($_POST['pass']);
    $fieldset = ($_POST['fieldset']); 
    $id       = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
    $fieldset = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$fieldset);

    if ($fieldset == "add") {
        $sqlcommand="INSERT INTO members (student_id,student_pass) VALUES ('$id','$password')"; 
    } elseif (fieldset == "delete") {
        $sqlcommand="DELETE FROM members WHERE student_id LIKE '$id'";          
    } else {
        echo "Your information is incorrect";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `when i press ok it doesnt operate` what happens when you press ok? Does it get submitted? Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the error would be here

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password); // <<<<<<
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
$fieldset = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$fieldset);
```

I guess that's supposed to be

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$id);
```

And also you're not running any queries, as another person said, you're just setting up SQLs. Basically your script should look like

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $user="admin";
    $pass="whatever";
    $host="localhost";
    $db_name="login";

    $con=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $id       = ($_POST['id']);
    $password = md5($_POST['pass']);
    $fieldset = ($_POST['fieldset']); 
    $id       = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$id);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
    $fieldset = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$fieldset);

    if ($fieldset == "add") {
        $sqlcommand="INSERT INTO members (student_id,student_pass) VALUES ('$id','$password')"; 
    } elseif (fieldset == "delete") {
        $sqlcommand="DELETE FROM members WHERE student_id LIKE '$id'";          
    } else {
        $sqlcomand='';
        echo "Your information is incorrect";
    }

    mysqli_query($con,$sqlcommand);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually executing the SQL query anywhere. You need to run `mysqli_query($con,$sqlcommand);` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the query; use `mysql_query($sql);`
Hope it will help you :)